# Modeling non-standard actions in Backbone.js with Models and Collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, frontend

I'm working on a project where there's a "reading list", in this list are "reading list items" - they're an abstract concept, on the server-side they can be Books, Articles, etc - they're handled throughout with a decorator which abstracts away the differences, and that works out very well.

I'm working on something that looks more or less like this:

1. Collection of `ReadingListItem`s (backbone model)
2. View that represents the `#reading_list` (backbone meta-view)
3. Views that represent one `ReadingListItem` themselves, the bindings on this view interact with the model directly.

```
window.ReadingListItem = Backbone.Model.extend
   url: ->
     @get('_links').self
   markRead: ->
     $.ajax
       method: 'put'
       url: @get('_links').read_list

   markDismissed: ->
     $.ajax
       method: 'delete'
       url: @get('_links').mark_dismissed
```

This is a model, the view looks something like this:

```
window.ReadingListView = Backbone.view.extend

   el: '#reading_list'

   render: ->
     @el.empty()
     @collection.each (list_item) ->
       @el.append( new ReadingListItemView(list_item).render().el() )

window.ReadingListItemView = Backbone.View.extend

  events: {
    "click .js-mark-read" : "markRead"
    "click .js-mark-dismissed" ; "markDismissed"
  }

  markRead: ->
    @model.markRead()
    $el.fadeOut
    @resetCollection

  markDismissed: ->
    @model.markDismissed()
    $el.fadeOut
    @resetCollection

  resetCollection: ->
    // to trigger a redraw, I really do this:
    window.reading_list_collection.reset()
```

This works (*caveat* I've written this code for SO without actually running it, so it might be slightly wrong, but it's conceptually what I have right now)

Here are my questions regarding it:

1. It feels like defining verbs that aren't CRUD on a model seems to violate the backbone "normal usage", and I've not been lucky finding any information about how to handle this (acting on models in ways that isn't destroying them)
2. How does the collection know if a model had "something" happen to it (when that something isn't create/delete)?
3. Is there a better way I could model this list?
4. When the watch-list is too empty, it should refresh itself from the server, it's pre-seeded with ~20 items in JSON, and in fact only displays the first 10. (I might move this all to be JSON, since it isn't much of a performance win to seed the page)
5. There's something else that happens, that on the `markRead` / `markDismised` another view on the page is told to re-download the list from the server, to display a summary counter of the reading list, I'd like if this were bound to the same collection that powers the `ReadingListView`

Please feel free to comment if anything is unclear, I know that SO doesn't lend itself well to open-ended questions without concrete error messages, but I'm looki

Comment: I am ab out to sleep ;( i will answer this later

Comment: about 2) you can listen to the `change` event on a collection or even a `change:attribute` event, just bind it `collection.on('change:attribute', this.onChange, this);` ... not created an answer for this, but that should at least help you on your way.

Comment: So it would be possible to mark the model's attributes as `marked` and or `dismissed`, handle the AJAX for those actions for those, and the collection could manage it's internal state, refreshing when required?

Comment: You can also define and trigger your own events so `markRead` could trigger a `"marked-as-read"` event

Comment: What is considered beter practice? I'd rather stay mostly inline with Backbone's best-practices (as far as a young framework can have such) - so far as to model my problem as deleting/creating "read" and "dismissed" items on their own lists

Comment: The Backbone best practice is to do what makes sense for your application, Backbone isn't built like a straight jacket for a reason. I'd call "mark as read" a distinct action on the model so a `markRead`  method makes sense; if your models have a `been_read` property then `markRead` would trigger a `"change:been_read"` event otherwise a custom event would make sense.